# IF ELSE statement php

Tags: php, select, while-loop, if-statement

I have a form that stores your fbid after completion.  I would like to use if-else to check if the person has filled out the form.  To do that, I match the id.  However starngely the if-else statement does not work.

This is the if-else:

```
<?php


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","fbappsadmin","dbP@ssw0rd");
        mysql_select_db("jetstardatabase", $con);
            if($me)
      {
      $fbid= $facebook->api('/me');
      $fbme = $fbid['id'];
      $fbName = $fbid['name'] ;  
      $fbEmail = $fbid['email'];


        $sql = "SELECT fbId FROM orders";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        while (list($fb)=$result->fetch_row()) 
        {


if ($fbme ==$fb)
    {
    ?>
        <label id ="quantity" >Quantity</label>
        <div class = "form">
            <form action="" method="post"  style="visibility:hidden" >
                    <select name="list" id="list">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Buy!" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
        <label id ="quantity" >Quantity</label>
        <div class = "form">
            <form action="" method="post"  >
                    <select name="list" id="list">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Buy!" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
}}?>
```

Comment: First, explain what about the if-else statement does not work. Second, format your code with proper indentation so it's easier to read and understand. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `if-else statement does not work`?  Either `$fbme == $fb` is `true` or it's `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code for debugging:

```
if ($fbme ==$fb)
{
    [your code]
}
else
{
    var_dump($fbme);
    var_dump($fb);
}
```

Then you can see, what's going wrong with your values and why they don't match